# How to extract the table name in the SQL FROM clause using Regex in Java?

Tags: java

How to extract the table name in the SQL FROM clause using Regex in Java?

Here is what I have so far. Assume there is no joins or nested queries for now. Also assume there can line breaks etc.

```
  public static String extractTableName(String query) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".* from\\S+(?=table)\\S+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(query);
    return m.group("table");
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(extractFromClause("select  from hello where foo=bar")); // expecting to print hello
  }
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect?

Comment: What will you do for `select * from (select a,b,c from table)`

Comment: as stated in the question. Assume there is no joins or nested queries for now. Also assume there can line breaks etc.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is mathematically impossible; SQL is not regular. That 'regular' in 'regular expression' isn't just a random name, like 'Joe' or 'Jane' or even 'Java' - it refers to an official classification of grammars. A grammar can be regular. A grammar can also be non-regular.

1. SQL is non-regular.
2. non-regular languages cannot be parsed by a regular expression.

Here are some choice examples of SQL that should hopefully empirically help you realize this:

```
SELECT "from" AS 'from' FROM 'from';

SELECT a FROM b UNION SELECT c FROM d;

SELECT 1;

SELECT a, b FROM (SELECT c a, d b FROM foo) x;

SELECT a, b FROM foo.bar;

SELECT a, b FROM c, d;

SELECT x FROM UNNEST(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c']);

SELECT x, y FROM TABLE(VALUE INT = ARRAY[1, 2]);
```

It gets worse; SQL is a spec, but there are no database engines that quite entirely implement it 100%, and all database engines have piled on a ton of extra features.

Go back a step; find another way. Perhaps, if these queries are being entered in a text file, make the one entering in these queries pre-list the queries they can fetch. Perhaps redesign the system; you seem to be under the mistaken belief that a query is neccessarily going to hit precisely one table, or at least, 1 primary table. That's just not how it works, so that 'simplification' turns out to have been an oversimplification, and you can't make it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using regex, I would recommend a sql parser since your tables probably do not contain always the string table. For example you could look at [JSqlParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser). You can find the [wiki](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki) here and examples to extract table name from sql here [Examples-of-SQL-parsing](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki/Examples-of-SQL-parsing)

```
Statement statement = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse("SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE1");
Select selectStatement = (Select) statement;
TablesNamesFinder tablesNamesFinder = new TablesNamesFinder();
List<String> tableList = tablesNamesFinder.getTableList(selectStatement);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex, `(?<=from)\s+?\b\w+\b` where

1. `\b` is used for word boundary
2. `?<=` is used for [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Here it has been used to look behind `from`.
3. `\s+?` specifies optional one or more whitespace characters while `\w+` specifies one or more word characters.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static String extractFromClause(String query) {
        String table = "";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=from)\\s+?\\b\\w+\\b");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(query);
        if (m.find()) {
            table = m.group();
        }
        return table.trim();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(extractFromClause("select from hello where foo=bar"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
hello
```

Comment: No, you can't. SQL isn't regular.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex needs to look for whitepace, then the `FROM` keyword, and then for any bunch of characters without whitespace:

```
\sFROM\s+(\S+)\s
```

You don't need the `.+` because you don't anchor the regex with `^` to the beginning of the line.

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TableName {
    public static String extractTableName(String query) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\sfrom\\s+(\\S+)\\s", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(query);
        m.find();
        return m.group(1);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(extractTableName("select  from hello where foo=bar"));
        System.out.println(extractTableName("SELECT a, b, c from db.hello where   foo=bar"));
    }
}
```

You also need to call the `Matcher`'s `find` method before you can access matched groups.

Note that this is fairly hackish and in the long run you might be better of with a real parser like https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser.

Comment: Your suggestion to go with JSqlParser is the right move; SQL is not regular. It is not possible to extract the desired string with a regexp; no matter what regexp you craft, I can craft valid SQL that the regexp will fail to properly parse out. JSqlParser is therefore the only right answer.